# PHP - pass same values to more than one page

Tags: php

i have more than one page to pass two values to it , the values are Sname & SID ..

i have used

```
$sql = "SELECT s.Sname, e.PID , s.SID
                          from student AS s
                          INNER JOIN evaluator AS e                       
                          WHERE (e.EID1 = '$id' AND s.PID = e.PID) OR  (e.EID2 = '$id' AND s.PID = e.PID)
                          GROUP BY s.Sname  ";
         $result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection);

         echo "<tr><th>Student Name </th>";
         echo "<td><select id='Sname' name='Sname' >";

         echo "<option value='' selected='selected'>--</option> ";

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {

      echo "<option value='$row[SID]|$row[Sname]' >$row[Sname]</option> ";


   }
```

and in the receiving page i put

```
 list($SID, $Sname) = explode("|", $_POST['Sname']);
```

and it works , but for the other pages i want the same values there , i had tried to put the same explode () but it doesn't work .. gives me an error says Undefined index: Sname + Undefined offset: 1 .. my question is how can i pass the same values Sname & SID to the other pages as well ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Also, while I'm at it: please, don't use tables for layouts. It recently has been recognized as bad thing (since 2001, or so ..).

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by session ,store value in session you want to pass

first you need to start session  by

```
<?php //must not any spave before php tag and must be on very first line 
session_start();
```

than store value you want for example

```
$_SESSION['views'] = 5;
```

than you can access value by on page you want

```
echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];
```

Comment: @user1806136 yes wait a second